# How to expire key after hr Redis with express node web API

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I new to the redis but somehow able to create the function with the set and get the key.
I'm using the azure redis to make all api to cached or you can create local client.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var Promise = require('bluebird');
console.log('hi data ');
  // Add your cache name and access key.
var client = redis.createClient(6380,'<name>.redis.cache.windows.net', {auth_pass: '<key>', tls: {servername: '<name>.redis.cache.windows.net'}});


exports.getV2PostById = function(req, res, next){
    var key = req.params.id+'-v21';
    console.log("Get============"+key);
    return getDataCache(key, req, res, next);
}

function getDataCache(key, req, res, next) {
  return new Promise((resolved, reject) => {
    client.get(key, function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
      if (data != null) {
          console.log('response key')
         return res.json(JSON.parse(data));
      } else {
          next();
      }
    });
  })

}

exports.setExp = function(key, data){
    console.log("Set============"+key);
    console.log(data);
    //client.set('key', 'value!', 'EX', 10);
    client.setex(key+"1", 300, JSON.stringify(data), function (err, reply) {
        console.log('set the key');
        console.log(reply);
    });
}
```

its working well but somehow the redis document say setex will expire in future.

```
client.set(key+"1", JSON.stringify(data), 'EX', 300, function (err, reply) {
            console.log('set the key');
            console.log(reply);
        });
```

but it not working once I call the get method it will return me `null`
can any one guide me is any wrong.

Comment: 'EX'   should be "EX"  it is string .

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
redisCache.set(key, JSON.stringify(data), function (err, reply) {
      if(err) throw err;
      redisCache.expire(key, timeLeft, function (err, reply) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(reply);
      });
    });
```